# Drag and move something in Interface builder, without changing parent/superview

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have some views in interace builder. I have a background view that takes up my entire view area
and above it I have some buttons which are NOT in the background view.

I want to drag those around to reposition them; but when I do, IB will reparent them when I let go of them.

That is to say, IB seems to only understand drag/drop in this case as a reparenting action; not a moving action.

Is there a hotkey, or something I can do to make IB just move things, without changing the parent when I let go?

This has to be the most painful part of working with IB for me.

Comment: let me confirm is this your question 
you have some components those are over on another components so u need them to on top right?

Comment: no anywhere. I want to have the freedom to drag things around without them getting reparented

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been bothering me as well. I've found a workaround which I find slightly less annoying. Sounds like a lot but it's really quite easy.

- Select the item you want to move
- Goto Editor -> Embed In -> View (this creates a parent view for your item)
- Resize (but don't move) the parent view to encompass the area you want to move to
- Move the item within the parent view
- Select the parent view and Goto Editor -> unembed

Also, since resizing doesn't cause the parent to change you could actually move a view with two resizes. However it's tedious to get the size right again which is why I like the embed method.

Comment: It's not ideal; but it's a smart solution given the restrictions. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

If you hold the command key down while dragging, the dragged element will not change superviews.  At least in Xcode 7.3.

Comment: That's the best answer for the recent versions of XCode. Simple and easy.

Comment: Thanks, the key bit here was "while dragging" and not before.  This has annoyed me for ages in IB.

Comment: Feels a bit like a grave digging but I have used that 'trick' all the time because I have found it here. Unfortunately in xcode 12 (not sure about previous versions) holding Cmd while dragging disables any guides and snapping. Anyone knows a workaround?

Answer (score -1):

You can press function key and drag the object: Fn + drag

Comment: If this was true life would be so nice. Just tried it 10 times. doesn't work :(